# can we replace form authentication ticket with custom object in form authentication module?

Tags: asp.net, form-authentication

In my project there is a requirement to use a custom object in place of  FormAuthenticationTicket. We have created a custom object with same properties as of FormAuthenticationTicket. Now we are using our own encryption method to encrypt this custom object. We have created successfully FormAuthentication cookie. But when we check context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated property, it remains always false. Here is the code.

```
    CookieData cookieData = new CookieData();
    cookieData.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(CookieConstants.DefaultFormsAuthTicketTimeout);
    cookieData.LoginToken = LoginToken;
    cookieData.Impersonate = (IsImpersonate ? true : false);
    cookieData.IsPersistent = IsPersistent;
    cookieData.UserData = "<<UserRelated Information>>";
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strCookieData = js.Serialize(cookieData);
    string encryptedTicket = AESEncryption.Encrpyt(strCookieData);

     HttpCookie httpCookie = null;
     httpCookie = new HttpCookie(cebCookie.Name, encryptedTicket);



        if (cebCookie.IsPersistent)
        {
            httpCookie.Expires = cebCookie.Expires;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cebCookie.Url))
        {
            httpCookie.Secure = cebCookie.RequireSSL;
            httpCookie.Domain = cebCookie.Domain;
        }
        httpCookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(httpCookie);
```

I know that this is a wired requirement.
Please help.

Comment: Why would you expect asp.net to be able to understand your custom ticket with it's own encryption scheme?  You have deliberately made something incompatible, and now you are surprised that it's not compatible?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your requirement correctly, you need to send custom data with the Authentication ticket?

In case you can do it like below.

Imagine that you need to send follwing data.

```
public class AuthUser
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserNo { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return UserID + "," + UserNo + "," + UserName + "," + Password; 
        }
    }
```

In your Login button click event.

```
 AuthUser au = new AuthUser();
 au.UserID = 1;
au.UserNo = "001";
 au.UserName = "chamara";
au.Password = "123";

 string userData = au.ToString();

  FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(

             2,                             // Version number

             txtUserName.Text.Trim(),      // Username

             DateTime.Now,                  // Issue date

             DateTime.Now.AddDays(555), // Expiration date

             false,                         // Persistent?

             userData                 // User data

         );
```

Retrieve User Data

```
FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;
string[] UserData = ticket.UserData.Split(',');
```

Comment: Thanks to your quick response. I think in my question I am not able to explain my requirement properly. Our requirement is to use custom object in place of Authentication ticket. We DO NOT want to use Form authentication ticket while creating form authentication cookie. We are able to create form authentication cookie with custom object but "context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" remains false always.